# What is a good name for a Date field

Tags: date, field, names

Which of these do you think are the best names for date fields?

createdOn/updatedOn
createdDate/updatedDate
creationDate/updatationDate

Other options? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized some go better with "_On", like "createdOn" and "updatedOn", while others go better with "_Date", like "startDate", "endDate", "dueDate", etc.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the sort of date field, where you use the field for. I usually use creationDate or createdOn.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the platform, language, environment, etc.

You might just use `Created` or `Updated`.  After all, you probably wouldn't qualify other field names like `NameString` or `LengthInteger`.

One convention I *do* use sometimes is to qualify date fields for what their values represent.  For example, some database types like `datetime` in MS SQL Server don't track what type of date you are working with.  Since many people store UTC values in these fields, you might call the field `CreatedUTC` to give the developer some clue about what type of value is in there.